# equivalent to shell "set -x" for python

Tags: python, linux

On Linux, is there a debugging tool for a python script that prints the lines of code before executing them, similar to the "set -x" directive in shell scripts ?

I know the debugging pdb module, but I am not aware it can do this (the stacktrace is not suitable).
I know strace, but it does not do this level of debugging.

Example :

```
def step_1():
    print("some step 1...")
    return 123

def step_2(some_value):
    print("some step 2... %s" % (some_value) )
    return "abc"

# main
x = step_1()
y = step_2(x)
```

Execution with the hypothetic debugging tool I'm looking for:

```
$ python t.py 
+ step_1()
+ print("some step 1...")
some step 1...
+ x = 123
+ step_2(123)
+ print("some step 2... %s" % (123) )
some step 2... 123
+ y = "abc"
```

Comment: `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` try it

Comment: pdb.set_trace() breaks immediately. But I want my script to run all the way alone, and just print the debugging info.

Comment: it stops, the execution, when it stop you press `n` and you will go through the code line by line

Comment: You want something that will print the line about to execute right before it executes?

Comment: And if so, isn't the stacktrace exactly what you need?

Comment: @zimdero 3 : yes, I want something that will print the line about to execute right before it executes. And also possibly the values of the variables.

Comment: @kabanus: no. When the script terminates, I want to know the lines of code that have been executed. The stacktrace when the script exits will not give this information.

Comment: I juste edited the question to take into account the previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [system trace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace), which is often used by debuggers for similar purposes, can be used to implement such a feature.  Here is a minimal example that you can tweak to suit your needs:

```
import sys
import inspect

this_module = sys.modules['__main__']
source_lines = inspect.getsource(this_module).splitlines()

def mytrace(frame, event, arg):
    if source_lines and event in {'line', 'call', 'return'}:
        line = source_lines[frame.f_lineno].strip()
        print('+', line)
    return mytrace

sys.settrace(mytrace)


def step_1():
    print("some step 1...")
    return 123

def step_2(some_value):
    print("some step 2... %s" % (some_value) )
    return "abc"

# main
x = step_1()
y = step_2(x)
```

Since Python is not bash and the execution model is different, you might not get the exact same output as seen with `set -x` in a shell script (for example the line `+ y = "abc"` with literal rvalue will not make sense in a Python context) but you should be able to recreate something similar enough to be useful for your needs, by interacting with the `frame` object passed to the trace.